# Hide prices from certain category in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have next code:

```php
add_action('init', 'bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in');

function bbloomer_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {
 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
   remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
     'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
   remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary',
     'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
   remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
   remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
   add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 31);
   add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_print_login_to_see', 11);
 }
}

function bbloomer_print_login_to_see() {
 echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')).
 '">'.__('Login to see prices', 'theme_name').
 '</a>';
}
```

This code is use for woocommerce site, and hides prices for not loged in users. It works perfectly. I want to hide price of products from a specific category. I supose that i have to change this part of the code in: `if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_category('my category') ) {  ...  }`, theoretically these changes should work, but i don't understand why i don't get the desired result. Who knows why the code doesn't work?

Comment: Will you hide the price for non logged in users for specific product category?

Comment: You will replace this **if (!is_user_logged_in()) {** with **if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_product_category( ENTER CAT ID HERE ) ) {**

Comment: Yes, i want to do this.

Comment: @Chinmoy Kumar Paul  i also tried this code, but it doesn't work

Comment: @FabrizioMele shared the code. You can try once.

Answer (score 1):

The `is_category()` method checks whether the current query is for an existing category archive page. Being woocommerce you should use the `is_product_category()` method instead, and to check for single product the `has_term($slug, 'product_cat', $product_id)` method.

This code will remove prices from archive pages and single product pages:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'hide_loop_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_loop_product_prices(){
    global $product;

    if( is_product_category('sold') ):

    // Hide prices
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    // Hide add-to-cart button
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 30 );

    endif;
}

// Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_single_product_prices', 1 );
function hide_single_product_prices(){
    global $product;

    if( has_term( 'sold', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ):

    // Hide prices
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

    // Hide add-to-cart button, quantity buttons (and attributes dorpdowns for variable products)
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ){
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    } else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }

    endif;
}
```

Reference: [Hide Price based on product category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673253/hide-price-based-on-product-category-in-woocommerce)

Comment: how to check if the user is not loged in and  in the same time if this user is not loged in, to hide for the same user the price for a certain category ?

Comment: You just need to `and` this condition to the `if` in both functions: `!is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: i changed next: if( is_product_category('sold') ) to if( is_product_category('mycategory') && !is_user_logged_in()): and if( has_term( 'sold', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ): to if( has_term( 'mycategory', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && !is_user_logged_in() ):, but my code still doesn't work. What could be the problem? – Asking 36 mins ago     Delete